# TSQL how do you insert rows from a table returned by function for each values in another table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, function, iterator

sorry for the poorish description it is really hard to explain what I am trying to do. But this is some pseudo:

```
foreach (row in Table1)
    insert Table2 select * from getValuesTable('text', row.Column1)
```

I'm not too sure how to get that initial join together because it will not allow me to alias the returned table from getValuesTable. Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cross Apply to execute the function for each row in Table1

```
Insert Table2(...)
Select ...
From Table1
    Cross Apply GetTableValues('text',Table1.Column1)
```

Comment: Oh wow never seen "Cross Apply" before.  Learned something new